# XMLHttpRequest cannot load, CODEPEN

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've had issue recently trying to pull a csv file from GitHub and receive the following error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jkeohan/D3-Tutorials/master/Tooltip/tootlip.csv. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://render.githubusercontent.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Now I understand why this is but recently I was examining some code on [codepen][1] and noticed that the user had used rawgit, which servers raw files directly from GitHub with proper content type headers, to pull data using the following html code:

```
<header>
  <div>
    <input placeholder="CSV, TSV, XML or JSON file" id="file" value="https://rawgit.com/anonymous/24251952a7e4d3c541a1/raw/fb8eaeeae97abf30b4ab75f34c72692f13ca2e9c/data.tsv"/>
    <button id="load">LOAD</button>
  </div>
  <div>load</div>
</header>
<svg id="con1svg"></svg>
```

However when I replace that url with the one below it errors out.

http://rawgit.com/jkeohan/D3-Tutorials/master/Tooltip/tootlip.csv

The actual file extensions are not relevant here as the js code determine the file extension defined in the url.

Answer (score 0):

Github is explicitly restricting the second URL, while the first is served up with an "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header that allows any site to fetch the content.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the issue.  I'm assuming then that the first url is pulling directly from github otherwise the same issue would have occured.  Can you suggest any viable workarounds to pulling csv files stored on github?

Comment: @JoeKeohan you'll only be able to retrieve the files they want to be retrieved that way. I don't know what the semantics are of the long "raw" URL (the one that works); maybe there's some process via Github to explicitly publish content that way. If the proper headers aren't present, however, browsers won't allow XHR request to fetch the content and that's that. You can of course serve the content via a server proxy of your own.